# Cast string into Pandas or Numpy dtype using same logic as read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I parse strings using the same logic Pandas would use when reading a CSV, where casting "False" to `bool` would give me `False`. I have text values entered by users that I need to insert into a DataFrame, they should automatically be cast to the dtype of the column being inserted to using this logic. The example below shows an attempt to insert a value into a boolean column but the result is wrong.

```py
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 0, 'flag': True},
                  {'id': 1, 'flag': False},
                  {'id': 2, 'flag': True}])

text = "False"
value = x['flag'].dtype.type(text)  # Want this to be False not True
x.loc[0, 'flag'] = value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and then convert the dtype of flag to its previous type. It will work for `"False"`, `"false"`, `"1"`, `"0"` etc

```
previous_type = x.flag.dtype
x.loc[0, 'flag'] = json.loads(text.lower())
x.flag = x.flag.astype(previous_type)
```

Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

x = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 0, 'flag': True},
                  {'id': 1, 'flag': False},
                  {'id': 2, 'flag': True}])
text = "False"
previous_type = x.flag.dtype
x.loc[0, 'flag'] = json.loads(text.lower())
x.flag = x.flag.astype(previous_type)
print(x)

    id  flag
0   0   False
1   1   False
2   2   True
```

Comment: This has the same problem as the snippet in my question, the value in the first row ends up being `True` not `False`

Comment: Edited my answer. Now check it out

Comment: Thanks! I like the JSON idea. I considered `eval` but it wasn't as lenient as the logic behind `read_csv` because capitalization matters so "false" would fail and similar caveats for other dtypes. One minor issue you might want to edit in the json example is you'd still need to convert to the correct dtype after `json.loads`, for example if the user text is "0" then `json.loads` casts that to `0` but that still needs to be cast to `False`

Comment: Yaa, needs to convert it to its previous type in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember, In Python

```
>>bool("faa")
True
>>bool("True")
True
>>bool("False")
True
>>bool("")
False
```

So In your case,

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 0, 'flag': True},
                  {'id': 1, 'flag': False},
                  {'id': 2, 'flag': True}])

text = bool("")
value = x['flag'].dtype.type(text)  # Want this to be False not True
print(value) // False
x.loc[0, 'flag'] = value
```

should do

Another solution might be

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame([{'id': 0, 'flag': True},
                  {'id': 1, 'flag': False},
                  {'id': 2, 'flag': True}])

text = "False"
value = x['flag'].dtype.type(eval(text))  # Want this to be False not True
print(value) // False
x.loc[0, 'flag'] = value
```

Comment: Changing the value of `text` is not a viable solution for me, the text is a user input. Users enter values into a GUI displaying a DataFrame as a spreadsheet like Excel and the DataFrame needs to update that value. Having the user enter `False` by submitting a blank cell would be bad UX, it needs to behave like they're modifying a CSV, that's why I'm looking for how to apply the logic behind `read_csv`

Comment: Ok. I have another solution tho it may not be to your liking but if you use eval(text) , you can get your desired output. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Also I'm not sure if you can use converters in defining the types of user input

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that works but may not have very good performance

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
value = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), dtype=column_dtype, header=None).values[0][0]
```